# Only call .uniq! on an array that is not uniq

Tags: ruby

I'm relatively new to ruby so bear with me. I have an array called `a`. `a` is an array of strings that can sometimes be unique and sometimes not. So `a` can look like this:

```
#an example of a unique instance of a
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

#an example of a non-unique instance of a
a = ["a", "a", "b", "a"]
```

I'm doing `a.uniq!.map!`. This works only when `a` is not unique because if an array is already unique calling `uniq` will just return an empty array and `.map!` errors out for being called on a nil object. What is the most ruby way of checking if the array is unique and if it is call `uniq` on it and if it's not unique I don't call `uniq` on it.

I realize I can do this in a verbose way pretty easily but I feel like there is some ruby syntax that will make it clean and simple.

Comment: use `uniq` instead of `uniq!` and all should be fine.

Comment: interesting about uniq! as BroiSatse said, use uniq.

Comment: Use `uniq`, not `uniq!`, and check out the docs.

Comment: General bike-shedding: this is why Rails has #try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map!` and `uniq!` change the array they are called on. The return value is `nil` if `uniq!` does *not* change the array.

If you always want the operation to return an array, use `uniq`. It returns a new array only with unique values:

```
#an example of a unique instance of a
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"].uniq
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

#an example of a non-unique instance of a
a = ["a", "a", "b", "a"].uniq
# => ["a", "b"]
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Ruby Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21)

> Removes duplicate elements from self.
>
> If a block is given, it will use the return value of the block for comparison.
>
> It compares values using their hash and eql? methods for efficiency.
>
> Returns nil if no changes are made (that is, no duplicates are found).

Why not first `a.uniq!` and then `a.map!`?

Answer (score 0):

### Avoid Methods That Return Nil in Method Chains

[Array#uniq!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21) will return nil if no changes are made, whereas [Array#uniq](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq) returns a new array, whether or not there were any duplicates in the original array.

Consider the following:

```
a = %w[a b c d]
a.uniq
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
a.uniq.map!
# => #<Enumerator: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]:map!>
```

As you can see, in this case avoiding bang methods in the middle of the method chain will ensure that you don't invoke missing methods on nil.

Comment: ...but this does not modify the  `a` variable (I assume this was intended). So the Bang after  `map`  is useless and you need an extra assignment:
`a = a.uniq.map{...}`

Answer (score 0):

**But I really like to *chain* the methods!** e.g:

```
@projects = *get_some_project_ids
@projects.append *get_more_project_ids  if need_more?
@projects.be_uniq!.map!{|p| Project.find( p ) }
```

So learning from the previous answers and from here: https://mudge.name/2011/01/26/passing-blocks-in-ruby-without-block/
I ended with this patch:

```
class Array
  def be_uniq!
    if block_given?
      self.uniq! &Proc.new
    else
      self.uniq!
    end
    self
  end
end
```